# Forgot to wash but said hamotzi

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing

If I inadvertantly forget to wash and said the bracha hamotzi, and have just broken the bread, but not eaten yet, what should I do next?

Comment: Eli, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking on register/login, above.

Answer (score 9):

In the Aruch HaShulchan OH 167:17

[LINK](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A7.D7.A1.D7.96_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.99.D7.96)

he writes that if one forgot, said the beracha of hamotzei before he made netilas yadiim, he can wash his hands and the washing is not considered an interruption, and therefore he does not need to repeat the hamotzei after he washes

Comment: <<he can wash his hands and the washing is not considered an interruption>>

does he wash with a bracha, or with without a bracha?

Comment: Are you sure he means that he may wash _and_ make the _b'racha_ ? The precedent case is one where he had already washed but forgot to say _al n'tilas yadayim_ yet.

Comment: Curiouser, please register. Because you've logged in from two different IP addresses the system thinks you're two different users. After you register, I'll merge previous incarnations of you into the registered account, and you'll have credit for all of your contributions in one place.

Comment: He makes the Beracha. A case brought in SA OC 167 7 (and see Hagahos HaGr"a 28) http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14326&st=&pgnum=245 in which the one making Hamotzi made the Bracha before one of the people he was being Motzi had a chance to finish washing. The washer's beracha is not an interruption since it is necessary for the meal.

Comment: WAF, remember that wiping the hands dry is the part of the Mitzvah that we make the beracha on, otherwise there would be a problem of not being "oveir laasiyasan". Which begs the question, why does the Mechaber state the case as where Reuven dried his hands and then made the beracha? It must be the Mechaber does not mean specifically in that order, rather that is what Reuven did in summation.

Comment: WAF, also take a look in the MB there, http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=112 , in which hemakes it clear that if the mitzvah of washing was not completed yet then he may make the beracha of al netilas yadayim.

Answer (score 1):

since the from icar hadin you could eat less than a cazait without netilat iadaim, I think you could eat less than cazait and then do netilat iadaim. but I'm not sure about the beracha